# Spring asynch method integration test fails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I created an integration test for asynchronous rest controller method. Which looks like:

```
   @Test
    public void shouldHandleRequestsAsynchronously() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/reports/daily?startDate=2004-04-13&endDate=2005-04-13"))
                .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
                .andReturn();

        this.mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].totalDistance", equalTo(100)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].totalPrice", equalTo(100.7)));
    }
```

The main problem is, that all the time I am getting the assertion error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Async started 
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

At line with `.andExpect(request().asyncStarted()`.To be honest I don't have any idea what is wrong.

My rest controller method is:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/daily")
public ResponseEntity<List<DailyReport>> getDailyReports(
        @PathParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD") Date startDate,
        @PathParam("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD") Date endDate) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(reportService.findReports(startDate, endDate).get(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

I read documentation once again and I sort this problem out. If you want to use method `request().asyncStarted()`, you have to wrap your response `Callable` or `DeferredResult`.

> - Assert whether asynchronous processing started, usually as a
>     result of a     controller method returning {@link Callable} or {@link
>     DeferredResult}.

Answer (score 0):

Also, The same error appears if the API does not exist or in case of a bad request.